# Azure Storage Queue - long time to process

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles, azure-storage-queues

I need to generate quite a number of reports and a report can take about 5 minutes to be generated, large amount of data, many different sources.

The client will post messages to an Azure Storage Queue. There is a worker roles that processes the messages and generates the reports.

If I want to scale this up let's say I end up with 10 worker roles that will process the messages from the queue and generate the reports. Then I will add messages into the queue like this:

- message 1: process reports from 1 - 5
- message 2: process reports from 6 - 11
  ........
- message 10: process reports from 50 - 55 (might not be accurate the range)

If my worker role 1 will take the first message and put a lock on it but the process will take 5 minutes, the lock will expire and the message will be visible again in the queue so the worker role 2 will take it and start processing it ... and so forth

How can I avoid that consuming the queue message is done only once keeping in mind that the task is a long one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Using Azure Storage queues, you should be prepared for all of your operations to be *idempotent*: In case your queue item is processed multiple times, the same result should happen each time. The reason I bring this up: There's simply no way to guarantee you'll process the message one time (unless you check the `DequeueCount` property of the message and halt processing accordingly), due to unexpected events such as your role instance crashing/rebooting or your queue item processing code doing something unexpected like throwing an exception.

Next: Queue message invisibility timeout can be programmatically extended. This can be done via the queue api or via one of the language sdk's. In c# (something like this - I didn't test this), extending an additional minute:

```cs
queueMessage.UpdateMessage(message, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
    MessageUpdateFields.Visibility);
```

You can also modify the message along the way (maybe as a hint to your code, to let you know which of the 5 reports has been complete. This should help your specific issue: In the event the message gets reprocessed, you don't have to process all five reports if the message has been modified to say something like "`process reports from 3-5`"). Note: You can combine the `MessageUpdateFields` flags via `|`:

```cs
queueMessage.UpdateMessage(message, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
    MessageUpdateFields.Content);
```

Lastly: If you're concerned with the length of time taken to process a batch of reports, perhaps rethink why you're processing five reports in each message, vs. one report per message. You can always read queue messages in batches. *This is getting a bit subjective, as there's really no right or wrong way to do it, but it's just something for you to think about.*