# Long-running Azure WebJob Gets Duplicate Message

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a long-running WebJob which imports an uploaded text file into a database. The overall process takes around 5 or 10 minutes. The job is triggered by a message (i.e., it's not a scheduled WebJob).

Looking at the log messages while debugging I see that about half way through the job another instance appears to be started (i.e., I can see the initializing log messages interleaved with log messages from the already running instance).

The second instance fails, but the original instance keeps on running and eventually successfully completes the task.

Do I need to dequeue the trigger message manually? Or is there a way to reset whatever timeout is involved to wait longer?

Here is the Functions class:

```
public class Functions
{
private static readonly ImporterFactory _importFactory = new ImporterFactory();

public static void ProcessUploadedFile( [QueueTrigger( BlobStorage.UploadQueue )] UploadMessage msg, [Blob("uploads/{BlobPath}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream blobStream, TextWriter log )
{
    StringWriter swLog = new StringWriter();

    LoggerConfiguration logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.TextWriter( swLog );

    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    if( config.IsDevelopment ) logConfig = logConfig.WriteTo.TextWriter( log );

    ILogger logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();

    logger.Information( $"{msg.SourceFile} uploaded for processing" );
    logger.Information( $"File type is {msg.UploadType.ToString()}, primary ID is {msg.PrimaryID}" );

    if( blobStream == null )
    {
        logger.Information( $"blobStream is undefined; is file available?" );
        return;
    }

    // if we got a zip file, make sure it has only one entry
    string ext = Path.GetExtension( msg.SourceFile ) ?? "";
    Stream src = null;

    if( ext.ToLower() == ".zip" )
    {
        logger.Information( $"{msg.SourceFile} is a zip archive, checking to see if it contains only one file" );

        ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive( blobStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read );

        switch( archive.Entries.Count )
        {
            case 0:
                logger.Fatal( "Uploaded zip file is empty" );
                break;

            case 1:
                src = archive.Entries[ 0 ].Open();
                break;

            default:
                logger.Fatal( "Uploaded zip file has more than 1 entry" );
                break;
        }
    }
    else src = blobStream;

    if( src == null ) return;

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader( src );

    switch( msg.UploadType )
    {
        case UploadType.CountyVoter:
            ITextFileImporter importer = _importFactory.GetCountyVoterImporter( msg.PrimaryID, tr, logger );
            if( importer == null )
            {
                logger.Fatal( $"Couldn't find a TextFileImporter Type supporting CountyID = {msg.PrimaryID}" );
                return;
            }

            bool okay = importer.Import();

            if( okay )
            {
                logger.Information( $"import succeeded" );
            }
            else logger.Fatal( "import failed" );

            break;

        default:
            logger.Fatal( $"Unknown import file type ({msg.UploadType.ToString()})" );
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Storage Queue - long time to process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873578/azure-storage-queue-long-time-to-process)

Comment: I saw that one before I posted my question. The facts & circumstances are a little different -- so far as I know I only have one worker role, and the file import process didn't fail and restart (I designed the import to be idempotent, so that wouldn't matter anyway). I just ended up getting two copies of the same message, so far as I can see.

Comment: Do you renew the lock ?

Comment: Thanx for the tip, Thomas. I hadn't specified a singleton lock status (didn't know I could do that). If you'd care to post that as an answer, I'll accept it as such.

Comment: No it is ok, happy to help ^^ but you should answer your own question to explain exactly what was wrong and how you solve this problem :-)